# Need to set new constraints for specific indexPath.row

Tags: ios, uitableview, constraints

I set my tableview constraints pinch to left and right at zero in the storyboard.

But depends on my indexPath.row, I need to set new constraints (inset & width). I've tried this without success.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch dataType! {

        case .mycase:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NoBrandDeviceFoundTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! NoBrandDeviceFoundTableViewCell
            tableView.isScrollEnabled = false

        var frame = tableView.frame
        frame.size.width = 343
        cell.frame = frame
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 16, bottom: 0, right: 16)

            return cell
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The frame of the cell won't be changed it's been set equal to the width of the table , you can hook the leading/left & trailing/right constraints of the items you want to shift and change their constant's value according to that indexPath in `cellForRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NoBrandDeviceFoundTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! NoBrandDeviceFoundTableViewCell

    if indexPath.row == <#someValue#> {

       cell.lblLeadingCon.constant = <#someValue#>
    }
    else {

       cell.lblLeadingCon.constant = 0
    }

    return cell

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you need to take cell leading constanint -  nslcLeadingCell
you need to take cell trailing constatint - nslcTrailningCell

based on indexpathrow contion match you need make condition

if indexpath.row == 5

cell.nslcLeadingCell.constant =  10
cell.nslcTrailningCell.constanct = 15
```